# Find repo from chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to write a piece of code that will "watch" any new helm chart added to a cluster and  figure out some details about the chart. For example, values used, repo of the chart etc.

I'm able to obtain the values for the chart but the repo url isn't stored in the chart.

Is there a way to get the repo given a chart ?

Looks like helm stores sources in the Chart Metadata but is there a better way to get this information?

````
type Metadata struct {
    // The name of the chart
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
    // The URL to a relevant project page, git repo, or contact person
    Home string `json:"home,omitempty"`
    // Source is the URL to the source code of this chart
    Sources []string `json:"sources,omitempty"`
    // A SemVer 2 conformant version string of the chart
    Version string `json:"version,omitempty"`
    // A one-sentence description of the chart
    Description string `json:"description,omitempty"`
    // A list of string keywords
    Keywords []string `json:"keywords,omitempty"`
    // A list of name and URL/email address combinations for the maintainer(s)
    Maintainers []*Maintainer `json:"maintainers,omitempty"`
    // The URL to an icon file.
    Icon string `json:"icon,omitempty"`
    // The API Version of this chart.
    APIVersion string `json:"apiVersion,omitempty"`
    // The condition to check to enable chart
    Condition string `json:"condition,omitempty"`
    // The tags to check to enable chart
    Tags string `json:"tags,omitempty"`
    // The version of the application enclosed inside of this chart.
    AppVersion string `json:"appVersion,omitempty"`
    // Whether or not this chart is deprecated
    Deprecated bool `json:"deprecated,omitempty"`
    // Annotations are additional mappings uninterpreted by Helm,
    // made available for inspection by other applications.
    Annotations map[string]string `json:"annotations,omitempty"`
    // KubeVersion is a SemVer constraint specifying the version of Kubernetes required.
    KubeVersion string `json:"kubeVersion,omitempty"`
    // Dependencies are a list of dependencies for a chart.
    Dependencies []*Dependency `json:"dependencies,omitempty"`
    // Specifies the chart type: application or library
    Type string `json:"type,omitempty"`
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The struct you've listed doesn't actually store the repository URL. It's just the metadata described in the `charts.yaml`. For example, [in Hazelcast Helm Chart, it's "http://hazelcast.org/"](https://github.com/hazelcast/charts/blob/master/stable/hazelcast/Chart.yaml#L13), which is not the chart repository URL.

When you execute `helm repo update`, Helm just downloads the charts from repositories and does not store later the repo URL. So in your case if you want to extract the repo URL for the given chart, you'd need to execute the following command (and match the right repo name):

```
helm repo list
```